# In which path Library(libTest.so) of installed application will be available

Tags: android, shared-libraries, apk

I have installed an application developed by myself, I want to know in which path Library(libTest.so) file will be available when application installed in Android Device?. And is it possible to replace that with other .so(new version)?.

Thanks and Regards,

Shiv

Comment: riddles all over... what .so file? What are you trying to do?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: If you want to get so in Apks, just extract the apk and find the *.so in lib/ folder.

Comment: In my application, I am using one algorithm which is written in C, so i have created a .so file of C code. And my requirement is i dont want to keep that .so file always in mobile device. I will load .so file only whenever i want to use the application through usb device. To meet this requirement i need to copy a .so file from usb to the android device to make my application run properly. So i want to know where .so files of any application will be located?, so that i can copy to the same location.

Answer (score 1):

If your app depends on native shared libraries they will be installed in `/data/app-lib/<your-app>` 
which is symlinked to `/data/data/<your-app>/lib` on a device running 4.2.0. Yes, if you repackage the apk and resign it that is one option you could use to replace the .so file.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is rooted, then you can access .so file from `/data/data/<your-package-name>/lib`.

```
Ex: /data/data/org.mypackage/lib/libTest.so
```